# Kivy Sound Module

Tags: kivy, apk

What kind of changes should be made in the buildozer.spec file to play an mp3 file using kivy.core.audio SoundLoader in an apk app? Or is it possible anyway to use an mp3 file? For instance you need to add "pillow" module to display images, and you need to add your file extension type to source.include_exts line. What would be the equivalent of this for audio files

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a requirement. However you do need to make the following changes in the buildozer file:

```
# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mp3
```

Comment: I just decided to use a wav file https://programmer.group/python-kivy-app-development-and-playing-sound-music.html .It worked fine without any problems. But thank you anyway